# Making beamerarticle display 2 slides from the same frame

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I'm trying to display 2 different slides in the from the same frame in beamer article format. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\mode*

\begin{frame}[label=test]
\only<1->{Slide 1}
\only<2->{Slide 2}
\only<3->{Slide 3}
\only<4->{Slide 4}
\end{frame}


\againframe<beamer:0| article:3>{test}

\end{document}
```

Is there a simple way to get "Slide 1" shown and then "Slide 1 Slide 2 Slide 3" shown in beamer article format?

Comment: And what about "Slide 4"? Also, what does "then" in "to get "Slide 1" shown and then "Slide 1 Slide 2 Slide 3"" mean? I am a little confused with your current description. Could you please try to elaborate a little?

Comment: Suppose I had a presentation where the words "Slide x" revealed themselves, one at a time. So the first slide would show "Slide 1", then next "Slide 1 Slide 2", the third "Slide 1 Slide 2 Slide 3" and so on. Now I want to be able to create handouts for these slides. Normally, it would just show the last slide for that frame, the one with "Slide 1 Slide 2 Slide 3 Slide 4". But I want to be able to show the 2nd slide, the one with "Slide 1 Slide 2", as well. I'm trying to use againframe for this but it doesn't seem to be working.